# Ruby string operation doesn't work on captured group

Tags: ruby, regex, string

This string substitution works:

```
"reverse, each word".gsub(/(\w+)/, "\\1a")
=> "reversea, eacha worda"
```

and like this, which is basically the same thing with single quotes:

```
"reverse, each word".gsub(/(\w+)/, '\1a')
=> "reversea, eacha worda"
```

but if I try to reverse the string, it fails:

```
"reverse, each word".gsub(/(\w+)/, "\\1a".reverse)
=> "a1\\, a1\\ a1\\"
```

I've played with it, but can't seem to get the reverse operation to work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I bump into this all the time. The capture groups are available in the block scope, so rewrite like this:

```
"reverse, each word".gsub(/(\w+)/) { |match| $1.reverse + "a" }
```

or since your match is the group, you could omit the group entirely

```
"reverse, each word".gsub(/\w+/) { |match| match.reverse + "a" }
```

Comment: Great, thanks.  Do you know why the reverse operation doesn't work on the string object directly?

Comment: Well, it did work on the string object. Literals are objects in Ruby. mpapis is right about that part: `"some string"` is an object so `"\\1a".reverse` reversed that literal string. If you wanted to interpret that expression inside the string literal, you'd have to surround it like this: `"#{\\1}a".reverse`. (That's untested code, but gives you the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You did ordered ruby to replace all occurrences of /(\w+)/ with "\1a".reverse

```
"reverse, each word".gsub(/(\w+)/, "\\1a".reverse)
```

You probably wanted to reverse result not the replacement string:

```
"reverse, each word".gsub(/(\w+)/, "\\1a").reverse
```

Comment: I think the OP wants "aesrever, ahcae adrow".

Comment: That is correct Jeremy. Each word is individually reversed, not the entire sentence.